# jquery e.target.hasClass not working

Tags: jquery, events, onclick, classname

I dynamically create a new `div` (with a "textbox" class and ID), and some other elements inside of it, and later on in my code I bind that `div` to the click event, and display the element clicked, like so:

```
$('#textbox_'+i).bind('click', function(event){
    alert(event.target.className);
}
```

This is fine, and it'll give me `textbox` as one of the classes displayed.
But `event.target.hasClass()` doesn't seem to work. So, when I do the following, nothing happens:

```
$('#textbox_'+i).bind('click', function(event){
    if(event.target.hasClass('textbox')) { alert('got it!'); }
}
```

I tried it a few different ways and it appears to me that `event.target.hasClass()` just doesn't work. Is there another way to deal with events or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 107, accepted):

You're trying to use a jQuery method, `hasClass()`, on a standard DOM element. You need to convert the plain JS DOM element `e.target` to a jQuery object, like so:

```
$(event.target).hasClass('textbox')
```

And you end up with :

```
$('#textbox_'+i).on('click', function(event){
     if( $(event.target).hasClass('textbox')) alert('got it!');
});
```

Notice the use of `on()`, the proper closing of the `click` function, and you don't need curly brackets in your if statement if you're only executing a simple alert.

Comment: Wow! okay that was simple! Maybe this is a little off topic, but what's the difference between $(event.target) and event.target? The former works with hasClass, but not when I try to alert .className.

Comment: hasClass is a jQuery function, .className is plain javascript

Comment: The first one is wrapped in jQuery, so it's a jQuery object and can be used with jQuery methods. The second is a plain javascript object returned in the functions `event` and can be used with plain javascript methods but not jQuery methods.

Comment: I needed to stop propogation on a .live listener; so I used the above tip and got `if(!$(e.target).hasClass("seeDetails")) return false;` and it worked great. Thanks!

Comment: Great solution. However, I'm getting this error when the document loads: `ReferenceError: event is not defined`. Any ideas?

Comment: @RalphDavidAbernathy - did you remember the argument, as in `...function(event) {`

Comment: I really like it when SO folks provide the "what you did" and then explain what you need to do instead. Nice job adeneo!

Answer (score 51):

If you want to keep your JS DOM element plain without using jQuery...

```
event.target.classList.contains('textbox')
```